# Null last in order by in Mem SQL

Tags: singlestore

Can someone help me how to use Null last in Mem sqlMEM, in RDBMS we have option for null last but in Mem SQL it does not supports

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

SingleStore supports it:

singlestore> create table t(a int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

singlestore> insert t values(1),(2),(null),(4);

singlestore> select a from t order by a;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
| NULL |
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    4 |
+------+
4 rows in set (0.03 sec)

singlestore> select a from t order by a NULLS LAST;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    4 |
| NULL |
+------+